# Laravel update OneToOne eloquent relationships

Tags: php, laravel

How do you update **OneToOne** relationships in Laravel

For example the code below will save the first time you want to save it. however i run into problems if i try to update it

```
$profile = new Profile();
$profile->dob = '20-03-1999';
$profile->bio = 'A professional programmer.';

$user = User::find(1);
$user->profile()->save($profile);
```

This is my code for when i want to update the profile:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$profile = Profiles::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();

$profile->bio = 'i now read.';
$user->profile()->save($profile);
```

**The error message:**

```
TypeError
Argument 1 passed to 
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() 
 must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, 
 instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've user_id so you don't need to get user collection.

Try these two ways

**1st way**

```
$profile = Profiles::where('user_id', 1)->first();
$profile->bio = 'i now read.';
$profile->save();
```

**2nd way**

By using a relationship.

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->profile()->update([
    'bio' => 'i now read.',
    'dob' => '20-03-1999',
]);
```

**3rd-way direct update**

```
Profiles::where('user_id', 1)->update([
    'bio' => 'i now read.',
    'dob' => '20-03-1999',
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must do either this :

```
$user = User::find(1);

$profile = Profiles::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();

$profile->dob = '20-03-1999';
$profile->bio = 'A professional programmer.';

$profile->save();
```

or this :

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->profile()->update([
    'bio' => 'aaa',
    'dob' => 'bbb',
]);
```

Comment: hi musa. i tried the first but got this message : Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist.

Comment: Edited my post. You need to get the first result. So, use first() instead of get().